# List ordering from SQL call

Tags: list, sql-order-by

I have a List being returned from a `daoTemplate.query()` call, using a `rowMapper`.

The SQL does an order by on a column, happens to be a date column, order by asc
when I use the List, am I always guaranteed that the list will be in the order dictated by the sql. can I depend that the first element (`theList.get(0)`), will ALWAYS be the earliest date(in this case)?

Comment: you need to tag this with whatever language you are using..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, At the time of execution, the first item will always be the most recent if you are ordering on a date column.